# JSXGraph: Events for a high or undefined number of elements

Tags: jsxgraph

I'm wondering if there is an elegant way to handle events for a high or undefined number of elements in JSXGraph. A simple example: There are n points on the board and the one which has been clicked on last should have a different color. For a few points I could just do the following:

```
const board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', { 
    boundingbox: [-5, 5, 5, -5], axis:true
});

var p = [];
p[0] = board.create('point',[1,1],{color:'red'});
p[1] = board.create('point',[-1,1],{color:'red'});
p[2] = board.create('point',[-1,-1],{color:'red'});
p[3] = board.create('point',[1,-1],{color:'red'});

p[0].on('down',
   function(){
     for (let i=0;i<4;i++){
       if (i==0) 
        {p[i].setAttribute({color:'blue'})}
       else 
         {p[i].setAttribute({color:'red'})}
     }
   }
);

//p[1].on('down', ...); p[2].on('down', ...); ...
```

But what if there are 100 or an indefinit number of points (e.g. points are being created by clicking a button)?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use the JavaScript `forEach` loop over the array `p`. Here is an example:

```
const board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', { 
  boundingbox: [-5, 5, 5, -5], axis:true
});

var p = [],
  last_idx = -1;

p[0] = board.create('point',[1,1],{color:'red'});
p[1] = board.create('point',[-1,1],{color:'red'});
p[2] = board.create('point',[-1,-1],{color:'red'});
p[3] = board.create('point',[1,-1],{color:'red'});

p.forEach(function(el, idx, p){
  el.on('down', function() {
    if (last_idx >= 0) {
      p[last_idx].setAttribute({color:'red'});
    }
    last_idx = idx;
    this.setAttribute({color:'blue'});
  });
});
```

For efficiency reasons, we keep an index of the last clicked point in `last_idx`. Then only one point has to be switched back to red. See it live at https://jsfiddle.net/vc3hLzp0/1/.

Comment: Thank's a lot! I'll have a look at this, it looks like a nice solution.